# booster have conflict in yii by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii, yii-booster

I am using extention booster in simple project yii,I think booster has conflict in yii project, I could add booster to my project but I have error  to all page in browser console:
for example ,  CGridview of filter don't work or other my jquery owner function don't work too.
 error in firefox console:

> TypeError: jQuery(...).popover is not a function
>
> jQuery('[data-toggle=popover]').popover();

error in chorom console:
[image]

How can remove my problem,
I added only a jquery (version 9).

Comment: @Samuel this is my console for all paeg , even a simple page have this error:  TypeError: jQuery(...).popover is not a function

jQuery('[data-toggle=popover]').popover();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I'm sorry for those who gave negative Unreasonable.**
There are some step for resolve:
1- remove default yii jquery.
2- add new jquery top of 9 version.
but you should not add new jquery to header.php.
You must to add jquery to config/main.php  and do other configuration.

main.php

```
 'components' => array(
...
'clientScript' => array(
        'scriptMap' => array(
            'jquery.js'=>false,  //disable default implementation of jquery
            'jquery.min.js'=>false,  //desable any others default implementation
            'core.css'=>false, //disable
            'styles.css'=>false,  //disable
            'pager.css'=>false,   //disable
            'default.css'=>false,  //disable
        ),
        'packages'=>array(
            'jquery'=>array(                             // set the new jquery
                'baseUrl'=>'js/',
                'js'=>array('jquery9.js'),
            ),
            'bootstrap'=>array(                       //set others js libraries
                'baseUrl'=>'bootstrap/',
                'js'=>array('js/bootstrap.min.js'),
                'css'=>array(                        // and css
                    'css/bootstrap.min.css',
                    'css/custom.css',
                    'css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css',
                ),
                'depends'=>array('jquery'),         // cause load jquery before load this.
            ),
        ),
    ),

...
),
```

It makes jquery9 placed above the rest jquery files.

```
 'depends'=>array('jquery'),         // cause load jquery before load this.
```